How to change parentNavigatorKey dynamically
I have a responsive flutter app. For navigation i used bottom nav bar on mobile, sidemenu on desktop. On mobile most of details page should be without nav bar. For remove nav bar in this case i used parentNavigator key:
  GoRoute(
   parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
   path: NotificationPage.path,
   builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) => const NotificationPage(),
   ),

But on desktop, side menu should be visible always.
How can i do it.
I've tried with global nav key, but it doesnt work
                    parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey.currentContext != null
                        ? MediaQuery.of(_rootNavigatorKey.currentContext!).size.width > 600
                            ? null
                            : _rootNavigatorKey
                        : _rootNavigatorKey,


Have you looked at package:flutter_adaptive_scaffold?  It manages to go with expanded left nav, compact left nav, or bottom nav depending on default criteria, or you can customize that.

thank you for your answer, but i dont have problems with hiding navbar in specific pages. I was wondering if it's possible to do with parentNavigatorKey
